# The PHP include is not working

Tags: php, html

I have researched so much in blogs and forums and can not seem to find the solution to this problem. I am using the Wamp directory: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\htdocs\lr

the lr at the end of the /htdocs is just the folder that I am holding my webpage in.

The code inside of my index.php :

```
<html>
<?php include('includes/head.php'); ?>
<body>
    <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
    <div id="container">
        <?php include 'includes/aside.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <footer>
        &copy; phpacademy.org 2011. All rights reserved.
    </footer>
</body>
```

When I load the index.php in chrome or any browser the only thing that I am seeing is the footer which happens to be the only thing that is NOT set up in a php include tag.

Here is the code inside of my head.php

```
<head>
<title>Website Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
```

Very basic code which only gives me more confusion on why it is not working. If you would like more examples of code that I am using let me know. I will gladly provide some as I really need this to continue creating the database for my login/registration page(s).

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, you are loading `http://localhost/lr/`, right?

Comment: change to `require()`. if the files don't exist, or aren't readable, you'll get an error saying so.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I am viewing the page in my browser from file:///C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/htdocs/lr/index.php

Comment: PHP cannot run from file://. Navigate to http://localhost/lr/ like @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: @MarcB I changed it to <?php require(); ?> and I am getting nothing different.

Comment: As Marc B said, change the include to require.  Also(and I know this is gonna sound ridiculous) try clearing your browser cache.  For some odd reason, I've noticed that sometimes the browsers don't like to refresh as told(at least firefox doesn't) especially when loading pages into the HTML document.  You could also try adding the parenthesis around the second and third include statements.  I know it doesn't make a difference, but PHP is funny like that sometimes.

Comment: @Robert I just had to move the directory to the C:\wamp\www and then it worked.

Comment: A tool you should be using => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that you were already using that directory.  Yeah, the www folder is your localhost, if you run your site locally, your files must be in that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that PHP does not find the files to be included.

Are you sure the folder 'includes' is in the same directory as your index.php?

Also, I would suggest to use "**/**includes/..." with a slash at the start to be sure that it searches the included files from the root directory, and not from the relative path of your index.php.

Besides, shouldn't your root be C:\wamp\www\ in WAMP?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you fixed it! I just pasted the "lr" folder into the C:\wamp\www and it showed what was missing. Thank you! Fellow developer told me to put it in the htdocs haha ...

Answer (score 0):

Try to close head tag first in your head include file, if that doesn't work, I will dig deeper :D

EDIT:
Sometimes there are problems with file path. I usually use:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/filename.php";?>
```

In Your case that probably be:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lr/includes/header.php";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the included file exist, this can give
you a clue to what is going on

```
if(file_exists('includes/head.php')):
    include 'includes/head.php';
else: 
   echo 'file either not readible or does not exist';
endif;
```

Comment: I just had to move the directory to the C:\wamp\www and then it worked.

Comment: do you mean you used the absolute path